# Convert String to Double in Mongo - 3.4.14

Tags: mongodb

I tried to convert a `String` to `Double` with the `$convert` operator

```js
       ...
       {
        $addFields: {
            uslDouble: {
                $convert: {
                    input: "$currentDimension.usl",
                    to: "double",
                    onError: "Impossible to convert str to double",
                }
            }
        },
        ...
```

The output error is explicit:

```bash
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$convert'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
```

My constraint is that I can't upgrade to mongodb > 3.4.14.

Is there any workaround to convert `String` to `Double` ?

Comment: Really? Version 3.4 is End-of-life for three years.

Comment: I am afraid you will need to resort to application/js level logic for your case. Consider upgrading your database.

Comment: Yes the best solution would be to upgrade Mongo but unfortunately other legacy applications are based on it and are not planned to be updated.

Then I wonder if by updating the Mongo - imagine to version 6 - is everything backwards compatible? Will the old drivers work correctly?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/?_ga=2.61419561.423741655.1675161923-1271365012.1667829920

Comment: You have to check. In almost every release MongoDB also removes some functions which have been deprecated before.

Comment: What do the strings look like?

Comment: like "2.034", "0.120", "5.001".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible, but I'm not sure about the performance.

The basic idea:

- Split the string into whole and fractional parts
- Convert each part to a number:
  o iterate over the characters in each part
  o multiply the running total by 10
  o add the value of the current digit
- Divide the fractional part by 10^(number of digits)
- Add the whole and fractional parts to get the final double
- Remove temporary fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      split: {$split: ["$value", "."]}
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      whole: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$split", 0]},
      fraction: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$split", 1]},
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      whole: {$reduce: {
          input: {$range: [0,{$strLenCP: "$whole"}]},
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              {$multiply: ["$$value",10]},
              {"$indexOfArray": [
                    ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
                    {$substr: ["$whole","$$this",1]}
              ]}
            ]
          }
      }},
      fractionVal: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {$range: [0,{$strLenCP: "$fraction"}]},
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              {$multiply: ["$$value", 10]},
              {"$indexOfArray": [
                  ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
                  {$substr: ["$fraction","$$this",1]}
              ]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      double: {$add: [
          "$whole",
          {$divide: ["$fractionVal",{"$pow": [10,{$strLenCP: "$fraction"}]}]}
      ]}
  }},
  {$project: {
      fraction: 0,
      fractionVal: 0,
      whole: 0,
      split: 0
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X4PVmFvupwO)

Comment: Thank you very much for this workaround! It works fine from the playground, I will try it on my local server. Performance is not an issue in my case, I am writing a migration file that will apply once on the database.